# How to use tinysvcmdns

Tags: iphone, mdns

I want to use tinysvcmdns (https://bitbucket.org/geekman/tinysvcmdns) for my ARM cortex microcontroller for audio streaming. I am using LWIP as a TCP/IP stack.
I have finished porting it on LWIP and now I want to test it.
According to the documentattion of tinysvcmdns I have to call the following functions.

1. srv = mdnsd_start() to start the main thread
2. mdnsd_set_hostname(svr, hostname, inet_addr("10.157.5.119")) to set the hostname and IP address
3. mdnsd_register_svc(svr, "My Website","_http._tcp.local", 8080, NULL, txt) to register a service 
   and begin an announcement
4. mdnsd_stop() when you no longer need to respond to mDNS queries

I am stuck at mdnsd_set_hostname(), which IP should I set. Is it my Apple device (iPhone) or my microcontroller device IP address?.
Another question when I call mdnsd_register_svc() is that a mdns query or answer ? and should I provide the same service published by my apple device (iPhone)?

When I capture the ethernet stream, I see that my iphone is sending a mdns query to address 224.0.0.251. How should I reply to such request ?

Thanks in advance